# Can minions alone finish a League of Legends game?

Tags: league-of-legends

Let's say both teams in the game stop playing, and aren't disconnected by the server time limit or kicked for inactivity. Will the minions eventually finish the game by destroying all the turrets + nexus, or will the game just go on forever in a stalemate as the minions fight each other?